# How can \tcbcolorbox be arranged to accommodate two optional length parameters?

Tags: tcolorbox, arguments

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox} %
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{setspace} %
\usepackage{xcolor} %
\usepackage{colortbl} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{layout} %
\usepackage{graphicx} %
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} %

\noindent Can this be modified to allow \newtcbox{\mybox}[2]...  with bottom=2.4pt changed to bottom=#2 ?

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][2.4pt]{on line, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!white,
boxrule=0pt, bottomrule=1pt, toprule=1pt, boxsep=0pt, left=1pt, right=1pt,
top=#1, bottom=2.4pt}


\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.00}

\noindent \,----------------------------------------------------------------- %

\noindent The \,\mybox{quick brown fox} \,jumped over \,\mybox[8pt]{the very lazy dog}\,.
\vspace{12pt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you have an infinite number of optional arguments with pgf keys. That is, I would just do

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
\documentclass[english]{book}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ %
%
%\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext} %
\usepackage{setspace} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,lmargin=12.5mm,rmargin=12.5mm,bindingoffset=12.5mm,noheadfoot,nomarginpar,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} %
\usepackage[a4,frame,cam,center]{crop} %
\usepackage{layout} %
\usepackage[skins,theorems,most]{tcolorbox} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm} %
%\noindent Can this be modified to allow \newtcbox{\mybox}[2]...  with bottom=2.4pt changed to bottom=#2 ?

\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{on line, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, colback=yellow!10!white, colframe=red!50!white,
boxrule=0pt, bottomrule=1pt, toprule=1pt, boxsep=0pt, left=1pt, right=1pt,
bottom=2.4pt,top=2.4pt,#1}


\begin{document}

\setstretch{1.00}

\noindent \,----------------------------------------------------------------- %

\noindent The \,\mybox{quick brown fox} \,jumped over \,\mybox[top=8pt]{the very lazy dog}\,.
\vspace{12pt}

\noindent The \,\mybox{quick brown fox} \,jumped over \,\mybox[bottom=8pt]{the very lazy dog}\,.
\vspace{12pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

While it is possible write macros with two optional arguments e.g. with `xparse`, I would not do that. You always have to remember the order of these optional arguments. What is more, if you want to add more options, you have to change the macro. Here you can add arbitrarily many without losing backward compatibility.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.